# Como fazer com que o programa continue de onde parei após uma exceção acontecer no meu try

Tags: java, while, try-catch, joptionpane

Neste trecho eu consegui o resultado esperado, que era não fechar o programa após a mensagem de erro caso o usuário entre com dados errados.
Entretanto, mesmo que eu esteja na 10ª pm, ele reseta para a primeira.
Então ai vem a questão, existe alguma coisa que eu possa fazer nesse trecho para que só peça o dado novamente da pm com dado inválido?

```java
//Entrada de dados
while(true) { //Solução para o programa não fechar após mensagem de erro
    try //Inicio trycatch
    {
        pm1 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 1ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        pm2 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 2ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        pm3 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 3ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        pm4 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 4ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        pm5 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 5ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        pm6 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 6ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        pm7 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 7ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        pm8 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 8ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        pm9 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 9ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        pm10 = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a 10ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "Digite um peso válido!\n"
            + "Tente usar .(ponto) para números decimais.\n"
            + "Não use letras, apenas números.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse código está sendo feito de forma não profissional. porque não guarda o número de malas em um array de inteiros e depois com um ciclo "foreach", faz o Input dos valores? Era código mais profissional. Se tiver dúvidas eu posso postar um exemplo

Comment: @BarrosKing Entendo, é que estou iniciando no curso, é somente a quinta semana, o desafio em questão foi atingindo, com as ferramentas que aprendemos até o momento, é que gostaria de aprimorar essa questão do reset dos valores, e não sei bem como fazer isto, porque eu tive que colocar 10 variaveis para guardas estas pms, sendo que imagino que um contador seria mais eficiente.

Comment: Foi colocada uma resposta com o objectivo falado por mim, se não entender alguma coisa pode perguntar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um arranjo de 10 posições primeiramente ao invés de fazer isso.

```java
float pm = new float [10]
```

Agora só percorrer.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < pm.length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        pm[i] = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Quantos Kg tem a" + (i+1) "ª mala? \n Insira abaixo:"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        i--; //Aqui irá diminuir o valor de i para que a linha seja repetida
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null, "Digite um peso válido!\n"
            + "Tente usar .(ponto) para números decimais.\n"
            + "Não use letras, apenas números.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado aqui funcionou perfeitamente.